# Formatting strings to match pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, string-formatting

I've looked through SO, but haven't found an answer to a question similar to mine.

I need to format currencies depending on locale.

Example:

I have the amount `11349` and my locale is somewhere in the USA. The format I pull from our CMS looks like this: `$#,##0.00`

I need to use that template to get the amount '11349' to look like this: `$11,349.00`

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this? If there is already a question on SO that addresses this, I apologies - I didn't find it, and I would be grateful if you could point me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) supports `Locales` and produces formatting as per your question plus avoids using regular expressions:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
System.out.println(fmt.format(11349));
```

Comment: I will mark this as the accepted answer. However - and I forgot to mention this in my question - the formats aren't always the ones you get when you use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)`

For my particular problem, [Evgeniy Dorofeev's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18274215/1073118) answer will most likely work out best.

Thank you, though, this answer is clean and readable :)

Answer (score 1):

If your locale is US then this should produce the required result

```
    String s = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00").format(11348);
```

Comment: Thanks! How would it handle floats?

What if I passed it `883.0`, for example?

Comment: $883.00 This pattern defines that the number will always have 2 digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Use Locale("en", "US")

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale); //getting currency
System.out.println(nf.format("11349")); //cast string to numberFormat
```

Then you'll get output as

```
$11,349.00
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a BigDecimal?